# Continuity of map and invariant measure

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $\mu$ be a limit point for the sequence of measures 
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}T_*^k\delta_x$$
for some point $x\in X$ and let the map $T_∗: \mathcal{M}(X)\rightarrow \mathcal{M}(X)$ be continuous at the measure $\mu$. Then $T_∗\mu = \mu$.

Above is a theorem. I want to ask, if we drop the condition that map is continuous, how to construct a counterexample?

Comment: Did you try? Do consider a discontinuous map $T$ on $[0,1]$ and the very particular case of your delta measure (it is much more complicated to consider arbitrary measures, although in general then it fails more the existence of a fixed point of the pullback). Note that what is important is that the map $T_*$ is discontinuous, not really $T$.